# PHP - getimagesize() redirect not working

Tags: php, getimagesize

Problem: getimagesize() does not work for some URLs, especially ones that are redirecting.

I googled around and checked stackoverflow but to no avail.

Here's what I see on my local machine:

```
var_dump(getimagesize('http://gan.doubleclick.net/gan_impression?lid=41000000015155731&pubid=21000000000506299&lsrc=17'));

> Array
(
    [0] => 120
    [1] => 90
    [2] => 2
    [3] => width="120" height="90"
    [bits] => 8
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/jpeg
)
```

and on my server:

```
var_dump(getimagesize('http://gan.doubleclick.net/gan_impression?lid=41000000015155731&pubid=21000000000506299&lsrc=17'));

> bool(false)
```

I tried other images and URLs, and they work fine. It's this URL that is giving me a problem. I also tried the following (on my server), and this *does* work:

```
echo strlen(file_get_contents('http://gan.doubleclick.net/gan_impression?lid=41000000015155731&pubid=21000000000506299&lsrc=17'));

> 4829 // This number means it works
```

The error log has nothing, and there is no other hints I can tell. I'm guessing it's something that needs to change in the php.ini

Comment: What does `echo file_get_contents(...)` output?

Comment: it spits out the image all over my console :)

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", "on");` what do you get

Comment: Same thing, no warnings either. Even checked the error log file.

Comment: The strangest part is that it works on my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `file_get_contents` works then definitely `fopen` would work

Curl would have been the best option since you are having permission issue but you can also use [FastImage](https://github.com/olekukonko/fastimage) .. to **read the image headers** and get the information instead of ***having to save the whole file locally***

Example

```
$img = new FastImage("http://gan.doubleclick.net/gan_impression?lid=41000000015155731&pubid=21000000000506299&lsrc=17");
var_dump($img->getSize(),$img->getType());
```

Output

```
array (size=2)
  0 => int 120
  1 => int 90
string 'jpeg' (length=4)
```

[Simple Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/F3cTcO)

Comment: This is probably the best answer since it makes the best of my situation, giving me faster code, plus the implementation quick and easy. I'll see if anyone else answers before accepting.

Comment: Really its does not makes sense having to download the full image every time just because of size ...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `allow_url_fopen` is disabled in your `PHP.ini` file?
You could edit your `PHP.ini` file or use `cUrl` instead.

Example:

```
<?php
//Download content
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://gan.doubleclick.net/gan_impression?lid=41000000015155731&pubid=21000000000506299&lsrc=17');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$file_contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

file_put_contents('file', $file_contents); //Put content in ./file

var_dump(getimagesize('file')); //Get image size

unlink('file'); //Remove the file
?>
```

Comment: I tried `ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 'On')` like you suggested, but it didn't seem to help. It works on my local machine, but perhaps I'll use a method like this.

Comment: Try setting it to 1 in stead of On see http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php for more information.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, `ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1 )` did not solve it though.

Answer (score 1):

hope it helps you. since there is 302 header on that link, unfortunately getimagesize dont recognize that header. you can fetch to you server to ensure getimagesize works!

```
    // fetch content to local
    $content = file_get_contents($file_path);
    $fetch_from_remote = file_put_contents($to_local_path, $content);

    if($fetch_from_flag === FALSE){
        // error
    }

    // defining vars to resize photo
    $file_info = getimagesize($to_local_path);
```

Comment: The odd part is that it recognizes it on PHP on my local machine. Perhaps I'll settle for an alternative, though.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options I can think of :

1) Get the file to your computer (use cURL or file_get_contents) and apply there any processing you want

2) Do a call for headers (cURL library), check if status = 200, if yes .. apply that function directly there, if other http status code then follow the redirect or ignore the file.