# Remote image size and dimension in PHP getting HTTP error

Tags: php, amazon-s3, remote-server, getimagesize, gdlib

I hosted images in Amazon S3. And I point the URL `static.example.com` to S3 Bucket. When I directly enter the URL `http://static.example.com/path/mypic.png` in browser the image is existed, I can view and download too. But when I want to get the size and dimension of image in PHP it is showing this error.

```
`getimagesize($path)`
```

And this is the error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: getimagesize(http://static.example.com/path/mypic.png) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found

Filename: views/template.php

Line Number: 98
```

I can store the size in database while uploading but that is not the solution for me, I already have 1000x images in S3. When I do `@ getimagesize($path)` the errors are not showing but no size, no dimension.

I also looked into PHP documentation [getimagesize (URL)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php#example-3085). The link example is suppose to support remote images.

Checking `php.ini`

```
Directive           Local Value     Master Value
allow_url_fopen     On              On
```

Where I am wrong? Is there better way to get image size and dimension of remote image in PHP?

**NOTE** I am 100% sure the remote image path is correct.

Comment: please use the search before asking your question. And about which part of *404 Not Found* in specific you actually want to ask about?

Comment: So if I ask you the question: *How to troubleshoot HTTP remote access with PHP's built-in functions like getimagesize?* you can perfectly answer it already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your `php.ini` file. The most likely cause is that your server isn't set to [`enable allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php). This is a setting that is sometimes disabled by default as a security precaution.

Also, as an aside, once you get this working you might want to make sure you're caching the results because `getimagesize` will download the entire remote image before returning results, which will put a lot of drag on your server.

On this last point, you might want to check out [FastImage](https://github.com/olekukonko/fastimage) as suggested by [baba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700401/php-getimagesize-redirect-not-working)... and it might just avoid the problem altogether if this issue isn't `enable allow_url_fopen`.

Comment: I can't vouch for any of the them, but the [php.net getimagesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) page has a few functions that purport to solve this issue (mostly relying on grabbing only the first few lines and trying to grab all the info from that)

Comment: checked `php.ini` and `allow_url_fopen` is already enabled, i edited the question.

Comment: Have you checked whether you can grab any remote images? Try grabbing on from another site you control.